# Heroku Python + CouchBase Custom Buildpack

Tags: python, heroku, couchbase, buildpack

I am trying to create a buildpack to install couchbase on heroku.
Even though, according to the web it seems i have done everything right and it has worked in order to install gdal and geos, i fail to compile libcouchbase.

My code and approach is here: https://github.com/mpetyx/heroku-buildpack-couchbase-geo-django.
I have set

> heroku config:add
>   BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/mpetyx/heroku-buildpack-couchbase-geo-django.git

and it installs the geodjango dependencies but i can not install libcouchbase.

Any ideas?

The failing ouput is published in this gist https://gist.github.com/mpetyx/8237990.

Comment: Your output has 'Couchbase Python SDK requires libcouchbase 2.1.0 or greater' several times, what version of libcouchbase are you actually trying to compile?

Comment: I think it was the required one at the time i uploaded it the first time.
I could not find the version number in the repo(my fault) and i will substitute it with the currently latest version, but on my computer it worked.
The heroku sandbox does not see my dependency. I am sure i just miss something. 
Should i somehow compile there? Or just uploading it unzipped should make it work?
Thank you very much!